# Magento Catalog Product Flat can not index

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sql, index

I got the following error, when I want to reindex my catalog_product_flat.

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

How can I change this / solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have  exceeded the row limits in your product flat data table.
This can be fixed by removing or disabling any attributes that you do not need to appear in the product flat data table

There are several documented workarounds for it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large

https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/innodb-create-table-error-row-size-too-large

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before we look at the workarounds, what specific value of the attribute leads to the appearence in the product flat data table? This so that we can disable this value for some attributes.

Comment: Check the attributes which are created but not in use,then  try deleting those unused attributes